# The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress - process is not defined

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am getting this error when try to run the test in Cypress. Can someone help me how to resolve this, please?

This is my index.js

```
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands'

// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})
```

[image]

Comment: Did you declare `process` anywhere? If it is defined somewhere else, did you include those files ?

Comment: Thank you @MohitSharma for reply. No I haven declare process anyware.

Answer (score 3):

The line where it errors

```js
const env = process.env
```

is only valid in NodeJS, where `process` is a global object supplied by the Node runtime.

Cypress has both a Node process to which you can add plugins via the file `cypress/plugins/index.js` and a Browser process where you can add code to `cypress/support/index.js`.

The error comes from a package called `ci-info`, so it looks like you have imported it or something that uses it into `cypress/support/index.js` or `cypress/support/commands.js`, or directly into a test.

Please check all your imports.

Comment: I just cloned a legacy automation project. It is page object model test automation framework. One of the page class has this

`module.exports = {
    commands: [pageCommands],
    elements: require('../lib/util.js').getElements( process,
              require('path').basename(__filename).replace('.js','') )
};` How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove `import "cypress"` from my test. That fixed it. 9.7.0

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me when I imported cypress within my test, removing that fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

This was the issue in my case , I **removed** it from my **test's** file. Now, Its working

```
const cypress = require("cypress");
```